# lstm different input and output shape

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

input shape

```
tf.tensor3d([
    [
      [0.01, 0.02, 0.03],
      [0.01, 0.02, 0.03],
      [0.01, 0.02, 0.03],
      [0.01, 0.02, 0.03],
      [0.01, 0.02, 0.03],
    ],
    [
      [0.02, 0.03, 0.04],
      [0.02, 0.03, 0.04],
      [0.02, 0.03, 0.04],
      [0.02, 0.03, 0.04],
      [0.01, 0.02, 0.03],
    ],
    [
      [0.03, 0.05, 0.06],
      [0.03, 0.05, 0.06],
      [0.03, 0.05, 0.06],
      [0.03, 0.05, 0.06],
      [0.01, 0.02, 0.03],
    ],
  ]);
```

output shape

```
  const ys = tf.tensor3d([
    [
      [0.01, 0.02, 0.03],
      [0.01, 0.02, 0.03],
      [0.01, 0.02, 0.03],
    ],
    [
      [0.02, 0.03, 0.04],
      [0.02, 0.03, 0.04],
      [0.02, 0.03, 0.04],
    ],
    [
      [-0.03, 0.05, 0.06],
      [0.03, -0.05, 0.06],
      [0.03, 0.05, -0.06],
    ],
  ]);
```

I am trying to use the `lstm` layers to create a prediction model. The problem is that I just know how to change `units` variable of `lstm` layers only.

I've been looking for a way to convert to `tensor3d` but with different rows. I could only find a way to turn it to 1d or 2d shape.

```
  model.add(
    tf.layers.lstm({
      units: 30,
      returnSequences: true,
      inputShape: [5, 3],
      batchInputShape: [3, 3, 3],
    })
  );
  model.add(tf.layers.lstm({ units: 3, returnSequences: true }));
  // Prepare the model for training: Specify the loss and the optimizer.
  model.compile({ loss: "meanSquaredError", optimizer: "adam" });
```

Which layers and variables do I have to put in there to turn the input of `[3,5,3]` to `[3,3,3]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of what can be done

```ts
 const model = tf.sequential();

 model.add(
   tf.layers.lstm({
    units: 30,
    returnSequences: true,
    inputShape: [5, 3],
    batchInputShape: [3, 3, 3],
   })
 );
 model.add(tf.layers.lstm({ units: 3, returnSequences: true }));
 model.add(tf.layers.flatten());
 // flatten is used so as to be able to change the size of the second dimension using the dense layer   
 model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 15}));
 // dense allow to remap the size of the previous layer to a different size 

 model.add(tf.layers.reshape({targetShape: [5, 3]}))
 // reshape to the appropriate shape
 model.summary() // will print the shape of all the layers; last layer will be [3, 5, 3]
```

Comment: Don't i have to reshape it as [3,3,3] since I want it to be like `    [
      [-0.03, 0.05, 0.06],
      [0.03, -0.05, 0.06],
      [0.03, 0.05, -0.06],
    ],`? But thank you so much! I was thinking of reshaping but then couldn't find the way to do it.

Comment: Yes if the desired output is [3, 3, 3], then the target shape of the last layer is to be [3, 3] which means the number of units of the dense layer is to be 9